# Hibernate mapping files plugin for eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, plugins

I am a new bie to the world of hibernate what I was looking for any plugin through which I can generate the hbm files . is there any plugin which will help me in generating the hbm mapping files not the simple one but relationship one also ..!in eclipse indigo.

Comment: You would at least get autocompletion and immediate compilation checks by using annotations to configure your entities rather than XML mapping files. Annotations are the way to go: simpler, safer, more standard.

Comment: @JBNizet I prefer XML dude..!!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html: the home of Hibernate tools:

> The following features are available within Eclipse:
>
> Mapping Editor: An editor for Hibernate XML mapping files, supporting
>   auto-completion and syntax highlighting. The editor even supports
>   semantic auto-completion for class names, property/field names, table
>   names and column names.